How does this modified Beltrami-Klein disk violate the postulates of hyperbolic geometry?
I'm self-studying Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry. And I'm wondering how my "modified" Beltrami-Klein disk model violates the postulates of hyperbolic geometry. To be specific, I use the textbook "Axiomatic geometry" by Lee, and the postulates used in the book read as follows: (The postulates are based upon Birkhoff's metric approach)

Every line is a set of points, and there is a set of all points called the plane.
The exist at least three distinct noncollinear points.
Given any two distinct points, there is a unique line that contains both of them.
For every pair of points A and B, the distance from A to B is a nonnegative real number.
For every line $l$, there is a bijective function from $l$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that the distance is preserved.
(The plane separation postulate.) Roughly speaking, it assumes the plane is separated by two disjoint subsets.
For every angle, its measure is a real number in $[0,180]$.
(The protractor postulate.) Roughly speaking, it assumes there is a bijective function from the set of rays in a half plane to $[0,180]$ such that the measure of any angle in that half plane is determined by the function.
SAS.
The hyperbolic parallel postulate.

Let's modify the Beltrami-Klein model. It's  the same as the original model, except a silly change: the measure of a angle is defined as the same as the measure in Euclidean geometry.
I'm curious which postulate this new setup violates.

I think it satisfies all but Postulate 9 (SAS), since the rest of the postulates are either trivial or can be verified by the same argument for the original Beltrami-Klein model.
The reason I'm interested in this question is that I was wondering why hyperbolic geometry essentially has only one model (or non-Euclidean geometry essentially has only one model because elliptical geometry actually doesn't follow neutral geometry postulates (Postulates 1-9) in the strictest sense). But, differential geometry is so flexible. It seems that SAS plays a vital role in the axiomatic system because it gives a strict quantitative constraint on the model. Any expert can let me know if my understanding is correct?

You're exactly right. It turns out that, in the presence of Axioms 1-8, SAS implies that every model of plane geometry has constant Gaussian curvature. To see this, note that Theorem 1.4 in Axiomatic Geometry shows that SAS implies there is a reflection through each line (an isometry of the plane that fixes that line and nothing else).  Then by combining reflections through two perpendicular lines, you can show that for each point there is a point reflection (an isometry that fixes only that point and sends each tangent vector to its negative).  ...

Thus in the language of differential geometry, every model is a Riemannian symmetric space, which implies it has constant Gaussian curvature.

Thank you, @JackLee Prof Lee!
